# Component interaction in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvLny.jpg)

**Problem Statement**

I have a situation like in image I have a layout with 'Save all' Button, this layout component has many component (direct or deep in hierarchy). All component has a method to save its local state data to server and each component has different form component.

**What is best pattern with react redux to call save of each component on click of save all, and is there a way to disable save all if no component has any change ?**

Looking for help in React/ Redux scenario , is there some pattern like Command Pattern to handle these scenarios  ?

Comment: please understand that image links can be broken. also add some code for better understanding what you are trying to achieve and have tried so far, might help people to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time , this is more of a design pattern question, so no code is added